# Setup words completion with Jetbrains

Tags: ide, jetbrains-ide

I want to improve my work productivity with Rubymine (Jetbrains) by adding autocomplete to most common words:
like if I type `b` and enter , it will auto populate `Byebug`, for Example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've got what you mean by 'most common words'... there is a ['hippie completion'](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/hippie-completion-expanding-words.html) feature (Alt+slash) that allows completing words already entered in file.
Yopu can also use [Live Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/live-templates.html) to expand certain abbreviations into words